# Form array validation Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel-5

I am currently stuck on solving this problem. I am new to Laravel and the MVC framework. I am struggling to create the dynamic form that gives the user the ability to add as many forms as possible. When the user enters the page at first it generates 5 form fields .  Here is a look at my code so far.

```
<div id ={{$id = "from".$i}} >


  <div  class="form-group col-md-6">


                  <div  class="col-md-6   form-group">

                        <label for={{$id = "Address".$i}}>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name = "address[{{$i}}]" class="form-control" id={{$id = "Address".$i}} placeholder="Street Address"> <!-- problem form array how does this work in laravel --> 


                </div>


                  <div  class="form-group col-md-6">

                         <label for={{$id = "city".$i}}>City</label>
                         <input type="text" value = "{{ old('city') }}" class="form-control" id={{$id = "City".$i}} placeholder="City">

                            @if ($errors->has('city'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('city') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
              </div>
```

How would I go about validating a form in Laravel 5.2 with  from array

here's my controller

```
  public function Postdata(Request $request) { 

             $this->validate($request->all(), [
                'address.*' => 'required|string',
               'city' => 'required',
                  ]);

               }
```

I am using a for loop to generate the forms dynamically.

here is the error I get

```
      ErrorException in ValidatesRequests.php line 49:
      Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be                    an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in           
  C:\wamp\www\Dynamic- 1.0\app\Http\Controllers\propContoller.php on line 34 and defined
```

Can someone please help or point me in  the right direction  thank you !

Comment: Try using `$request` instead of `$request->all()`

Comment: Also it is better to define validation rules in your custom request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You man ! this is the solution I end up with

```
  <div  class="form-group col-md-6">


                  <div  class="col-md-6   form-group">

                        <label for={{$id = "Address".$i}}>Address</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="address[{{$i}}]" class="form-control" id={{$id = "Address".$i}} placeholder="Street Address">


                </div>
```

in post request i did this

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

      /**
        * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
        *
        * @return array
       */

    public function rules() {

    $rules = [];

       foreach($this->request->get('address') as $key => $val) {

       $rules['address.'.$key] = 'required';

       }

       return $rules;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add `name="city[{{$i}}]"`
2. Create a specific request with php artisan make:request PostRequest
3. Change `public function Postdata(Request $request) {` to `public function Postdata(PostRequest $request) {`
4. Remove the validate function call from your controller
5. Go to /app/Http/Requests/PostRequest.php
6. Then edit the rules function to something like this ...

.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    foreach($this->request->get() as $key => $val)
    {
        $rules['address.' . $key] = 'required';
        $rules['city.' . $key] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Just a general idea. See if that helps.